# Does EOS Storage support image, audio & video storage?

Tags: storage

Where should media heavy dApps store their png, mp3, mp4 etc. files? Should dApps developers who have intentions of building DACs store media files in central servers like AWS S3 for a predictable user experience or will EOS Storage be an equally good alternative?

Answer (score 3):

Devs will be able to store their files (png, mp3, mp4 ect...) with Block Producers hardware through EOS Storage which offers a decentralized storing service by locking eos tokens.

More information here : https://steemit.com/eos/@eosio/eos-io-storage-white-paper-now-available